# set the css attribute value for an element with a property that gets data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, razor

How can i set the css attributes or  attributes when the value of the attributes are coming from properties in a model?

For an example i want to change the body background-color, the value for the background-color is @Model.BgColor. The @model.BgColor gets the data from the sql database.

I dont know how to get the BgColor property from the model in css. And when i try with this setup in _Layout i get an error that Object reference not set to an instance of an object.:

```
@model ItbTid.Models.DynCss
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <style>
       body{
            background-color:@Model.BgColor;
           }
    </style>
</head>
```

Summary:
How can i set the css attribute value for an element with a property located in DynCss model that gets the data from database

Comment: How do you instanciate your model ? Could you post the code of it ?

Comment: I would love to know whether or not this is possible! Did you ever solve the problem?